# SublimeText with screen: Remote command too long

Tags: screen, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I use SublimeText3 (`Sublime Text Build 3059`) to edit my code and terminal (trough `screen` (`Screen version 4.01`)) to execute it. To send code lines into screen automatically I use Sublime plugin [SendText](https://github.com/wch/SendText).

**My problem is** when I select more than 16 lines of code screen can't execute them and gives "Remote command too long" error.

**My questions are**:

1. Is it possible to solve this problem (send much more lines of code into screen)?
2. Is there an alternative way to send Sublime code lines into terminal/screen?

Comment: what os? linux or mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problem related to max length of screen's command. It is not connected with number of lines of selection.

There's pull request about this on [SendText repo](https://github.com/wch/SendText/issues)

if you want to have it ASAP, do the following:

```
# add in 
# class SendSelectionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

        elif prog == "screen":
            # Get the full pathname of the tmux, if it's
            progpath = settings.get('paths').get('screen')
            # If path isn't specified, just call without path
            if not progpath:
                progpath = 'screen'

            if len(selection)<2000:
                subprocess.call([progpath, '-X', 'stuff', selection])
            else:
                with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
                    with open(tmp.name, 'w') as file:
                        file.write(selection)
                        subprocess.call([progpath, '-X', 'stuff', ". %s\n" % (file.name)])
```

From now on you are able to **execute unlimited** number of lines :).

Comment: there is limitation in max length of arguments passed via command line. This solution uses intermediate temp file for passing selected text.